# Append excel cell contents to new excel file

Tags: java, webdriver, apache-poi, selenium-webdriver, jxl

I have a piece of code that reads the contents and pastes it into the new excel file

The code is

```
for(int rownum=2; rownum<=datatable.getRowCount(testName); rownum++)
    for(int colnum=1; colnum<=datatable.getColumnCount(testName); colnum++) {
        datatable.getCellData(testName, "Serial", rownum);
        // Get value of other column  Serial :)
        String getdata = datatable.getCellData(testName, "Rules", rownum);
        if (datatable.getCellData(testName, "Serial", rownum).equals(serial)) {
            datatable.getCellData(testName, colnum, rownum);
            datatable.setCellData(testName, "Result", rownum,"PASS" );
            datatable = new Xls_Reader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//src//config//Result.xlsx");
            datatable.setCellData("Data Sheet", "Results", rownum,"PASS" );
            datatable.setCellData("Data Sheet", "Summary", rownum, getdata);
        }
    }
```

Now this is passed as (String ,string) and this is for a single test case that run. The problem is when I insert the Contents to Result it will be stored in at  cell 2, 3 . This will be overwritten again and again. I want to append all the multiple executed cases which is in multiple sheet and the Result must be appended. Is that possible ? Please help.

Comment: It's not very clear as to what all these functions do. Could you at least explain a bit more what we're seeing here? In particular what the setCellData() parameters are? From what I can see you have a rownum value in there which is used to specify the row number of every piece of data you put into the excel file. Is that correct, or does the overwriting happen because it sets the data of the same cell every time because it's using the same cell coordinates?

Comment: Also, note that the for loop condition is checked every time a loop execution is completed. If you're actually adding rows to your document, the values inside the condition part of the for loop statement will change (datatable.getRowCount(testName) and datatable.getColumnCount(testName)). To avoid this, you could store the values in variables before starting the loops. This also adds to the code clarity.

Comment: It is a design for a Data Driven Framework. In the sheet corresponding to the testname it will iterate the rows and 
print the result pass/fail in the "Result column" getCellDate will fetch the values of the corresponding sheet, column num and row.

Comment: Serial is a column where i have given the serial#. if it's 1 it will fetch the row# and col# and compare,setCellData will write the values of what is in the particular row. then i have passed the same results in another sheet called "Data Sheet."All are workinf fine.

Comment: If it is in another testname that is the "sheet" it will pass the String testname and the String Serial# and this is how it works. Now each time this will print the results in the "Data Sheet" in the row 1,2 and so on. If i run a test suite the last test run will be there in the Data Sheet file. I need to append all the test suite results column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to do a wild guess, but I think I know what's going on.

Before the start of this snippet, you have read in an XSL sheet, stored in the dataSheet variable. The for loops at the start of the snippet will look at the contents of the dataSheet variable to check the completion condition for every iteration.

If the serial value is equal to some value, you do some things, then overwrite the datasheet variable with a new document, in which you proceed to store a few values. When the loop completes, it will look at that new datasheet whether the loop is complete, and as far as I can see will just go like this forever, replacing the original document on every iteration.

In order to fix this, at least put the newly created data sheet in a separately named variable, and store the width and height of the original data sheet in variables before entering the loops so they're not altered during the execution of the loops. By the looks of it you're also fetching data from the data sheet without actually using it, or is that just me?

Comment: ya, Some cell value are fetched and entered in the new sheet. ThankYou